# Customizing the biblatex style authoryear

Tags: biblatex

I am aware of the fact that very similar problems have been discussed here before, but sadly I still can't figure out the following:

I need to customize the standard `authoryear` `@book` style to look like this:

> Last Name, First Name (year): Title. Location, Publisher.

(all non-italic)

Could anyone help me out here with undoing the standard italic title and the colon after the location?
Up until now, I only managed to change the period after (year) to a colon with:

```
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
```

Comment: If your goal is as straightforward as it sounds, you're simply looking for `\DeclareFieldFormat{<field>}{#1}`, where `<field>` is things like `title`, `booktitle`, `maintitle`, `journaltitle`, and so on.  If it's not that simple (I suspect it isn't), we'll need more information.

Comment: What about the other entry types? Is there any modification to be applied to those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The title formatting

You can reliably assume that the basic formatting applied to titles can be affected by `\DeclareFieldFormat`. In this case it's simple:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}
```

But you may well want to modify it for other entry types as well. In extreme cases you can clear all type-specific formatting with the starred version of the command; but in this case I've assumed you want to leave the formats for, e.g., article titles, unchanged.

### The location and publisher

If you look at `standard.bbx` (which is in turn used by `authoryear.bbx`) you can work out pretty quickly from looking at the basic drivers that it is a `bibmacro` called `publisher+location+date` that formats these elements. If we look at that macro (in `standard.bbx` we find, in the middle of it, these lines:

```
 \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
```

Immediately before the `publisher` is printed out. It's the second of these lines that prints our colon. So we can change that so that the entire `bibmacro` is defined as follows

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

Don't worry about the reference to the date: it won't be printed because the `date` bibmacro knows it already has been. But it's a basic rule of changing things in biblatex that you change as little as possible.

This change won't just affect the `book` entry type of course. But that's probably what you want: one expects consistency.

### The punctuation

As you have worked out, the punctuation is changed with

```
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\begin{document}

\nocite{cotton}

\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1) You might also like to mention the starred version of `\DeclareFieldFormat`, it clears all type-specific formatting before applying the new one.

Comment: @moewe In this case I think the unstarred version is what's needed, but I'll make an edit.

Comment: Certainly if the change is only to apply to `@book` (there starred version does not even allow for the optional `type` argument), but if all `title`s are to be formatted as-is, the starred version comes in handy.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It really works like a charm! I even think, I understand the alternations made ;)
However, naturally, I have more literature types to alter. Could you help me there once more? I'll post it as an answer to my original question.

Comment: @SimonBeck If you have other questions, it's better to post a fresh question, preferably with a MWE -- you can adapt my answer, I expect, to provide one.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see your reply in time. To not cause any more confusion, I think I'll better leave it this way.. (What's a MWE?)

Comment: I think it will cause more confusion to leave it this way, actually! A MWE is a "minimal working example" -- see here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that. Basically it's very helpful to have a "sample" document which people can play with.

Comment: Okey, I'll change it. Thanks for pointing it out!