# Bibliography style: name and year in text + alphabetically ordered and numbered list at the end

Tags: bibliographies

Is it possible to have a citation style by name and year in text and alphabetically ordered and numbered list at the end?

Comment: Yes, check the `biblatex`-package and its `authoryear`-style. For numbering the bib see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61374/adding-numbers-to-author-year-citations-in-list-of-references

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, consider this example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{paperA,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2003},
    author = {Alpha, Author},
    title = {AAA Title of Paper},
}
@inproceedings{paperB,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2002},
    author = {Bravo, Author},
    title = {BBB Title of Paper},
}
@inproceedings{paperC,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2004},
    author = {Charlie, Author},
    title = {CCC Title of Paper},
}
@inproceedings{paperD,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2001},
    author = {Bravo, Author},
    title = {DDD Title of Paper},
}
@inproceedings{paperE,
    booktitle = {Proceedings},
    year = {2001},
    author = {Bravo, Author},
    title = {BEE Title of Paper},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname}

% Make numbered
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\enumerate{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endenumerate}
{\item}

\begin{document}

Text citation style:
\begin{itemize}
\item \cite{paperA}
\item \cite{paperB}
\item \cite{paperC}
\item \cite{paperD}
\item \cite{paperE}
\end{itemize}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It provides the following style in text and bibliography:

[image: bibliography]

To move forward from here, consider the following resources:

- More on authoryear style:

  - Formatting bibliography style: [Customizing the biblatex style authoryear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174349/customizing-the-biblatex-style-authoryear)
  - Changing citation style to have parentheses around year: [biblatex, authoryear-icomp: brackets around the year in footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39919/biblatex-authoryear-icomp-brackets-around-the-year-in-footnotes)
- Original source for enumerating the bibliography: [Biblatex enumerating sorted bibliography (using authoryear-ibid style)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24501/biblatex-enumerating-sorted-bibliography-using-authoryear-ibid-style)
- Differences between `biblatex` and `bibtex`: [What is the difference between bibtex and biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8411)
- Basics on `biblatex`: [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509)